# Android : file is not downloaded from amazon s3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, download

In my Android Application Image files, audio files and video files are downloaded from Amazon S3.
It works in Android Phones, but in Tablets, it in gives Exception like :

```
08-29 11:16:08.021: I/System.out(6793): Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID:   
31FC5A42FF86E0DC, AWS Error Code: RequestTimeTooSkewed, AWS   
Error Message: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.,   
S3 Extended Request ID: hAySod5LYjYZEzHQDtqzVpBuWneufepFqmjhmeqlEefyra285CbnXxJK7UP8Ye0p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RequestTimeTooSkewed** - date-time of you android phone and actual amazon s3 server time is different. So correct your android phone time and then retry.

Or You can ...

1. Connect to an AWS server to obtain response headers.
2. If connect successfully get 200 response code
3. Retrieve the time according to AWS, based on the Date header
4. Calculate the difference between the current time according to AWS, and the current time according to your computer's clock.

Comment: i have also same problem but i don't know how to find time zone difference.?

Comment: What's step 5. ? I can' find a "setDateTime()" method anywhere in the Amazon AWS API.